# Looping through a JSON element in AngularJS

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I have the following `ng-repeat` code:

```
<li ng-repeat="vid in vids | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
       {{vid.title}}
</li>
```

My question is, can I loop through vids and print out each and every key and value if I don't know the key name?

So sort of how I would do it in php:

```
<?php
foreach ($vids as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . "=" . $val;
}
?>
```

Comment: vid = $val, $index = $key... http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Comment: My previous comment is wrong in the context of objects. I expected an array because of =>. +1 for a good question and +1 for Ajay for a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am totally not sure about question but it should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body  ng-controller="testctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="vid in vids">
        <span ng-repeat ="(key, value) in vid">{{key}} ,{{value}}</span>
    </div>
  <script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('testctrl', function ($scope) {
          $scope.vids = [{ 'adam': 10, 'amalie': 12 }, { 'adam': 12, 'amalie': 12 }];
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```